# Make "About" page more site specific

Tags: feature-request, help-center

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/about doesn't describe what the site is about.

It should have a link and a short quote  from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq

> Code golf is a special type of programming puzzle where the shortest
>   correct code submission wins.
>
> All questions on this site, whether a programming puzzle or a code
>   golf, should have …
>
> An objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to
>   indisputably decide which entry should win.
>
> A clear specification of what constitutes a correct submission. Test
>   cases are highly encouraged.
>
> "Tips for golfing in some language"
>
> These questions are surprisingly hard to write well. Help may be
>   available on the Puzzle Lab chat or the meta Sandbox, and the use of
>   these resources is encouraged.

Also the header of the section "We're a little bit different from other sites" is confusing.
It is about how StackExchange sites are different from other sites, but doesn't described how "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf site" is different to other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: BTW--This is not languishing unanswered because no one has looked at it, but because I'm preparing for a job interview.

Comment: @dmckee Good luck with your interview!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we get a custom Tour page?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8441/can-we-get-a-custom-tour-page) - The "About" page is now referred to as the "Tour"

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that we don't have fine grained control of the formatting of that page.

For instance the *"We're a little bit different from other sites"* bit is not available for editing.

I largely agree that the text above there could use some help but I'm not clear what ti should be. Whatever it is, it will appear centered and I can't do bullet lists.